# Visual studios Team Edition and Professional Edition installed concurrently

Tags: windows, windows-xp, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual studios 2008 Team edition installed already. I need to have the Professional edition installed also.  Certain projects the class runs only run on the Professional edition and we use the team version for everything else.

I am running Windows XP on a Dell Inspriron.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried just installing it?

Answer (score 0):

With VS 2008 the editions all build on one another. Installing Pro will only add extra installation options (so service packs take much longer to run and it modifies each install<sup>1</sup>). Using VS will be no different: you will see the features of the most advanced feature.

As each Team Edition is a super-set of Pro it would require special effort to make create something that worked in Pro but not in Team (imagine creating something that would run in Win7 Pro but not Ultimate).

---

<sup>1</sup> As I found out where I had ended up with Pro and then Ultimate installed.

Comment: Yes, I wonder why something should work on Pro but not on Team System. Things you make with an Express version works with Pro too so what gives? Also: No, you can't install them side by side, they will go on top of each other and extend each other.